# "Sql" statement in Tableau for subscription history in CiviCRM

Tags: mysql, sql, tableau-api, civicrm

CiviCRM stores it group history in a mysql table called subscription history. The relevant columns are contact-id, group-id, subscription status and subscription date.

Subscription status is basically Added and Removed.

Depending on a certain group-id has subscription date for Removed after subscription date for Added, the contact is part of the group or not.

Example mysql table:

- Contact-id   ;    Group-id  ;   Subscription status  ;  Subscription date
- 3                  ;    6517        ;   Added                       ;  2014-01-01
- 3                  ;    6517        ;   Removed                  ;  2014-05-01
- 3                  ;    6514        ;   Added                       ;  2014-05-01
- 22517          ;    6517        ;   Added                       ;  2014-04-01

This would give these values:

- Month ; count per group
- Jan     ; 6517-1
- Feb     ; 6517-1
- Mar     ; 6517-1
- April    ; 6517-2
- May    ; 6517-1 & 6514-1

I am using Tableau to make statistics, and they have the possibility to add SQL-like calculations.

The need is writing a statement that put in a Tableau-graph can give me count of group members on y-axis and date on x-axis.

Any help and tip appreciated, even if it is at a purely logical level as well.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what defines a group. Could you use some examples. Additionally, can you show us some work you have already tried and what went wrong (and what you want to achieve)

Comment: A group is a unique value as group-id. Will edit in an example.

Comment: Sorry for bad layout, but I don't know how to succesfully show a table structure

Comment: Don't worry it's good enough. Not very straight forward to achieve what you want. Need to reshape that table a little bit. Will try to formulate something later